# Determine the max value of a group, and display that row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, excel-2016

I've got a few thousand rows in an excel spreadsheet, which (simplified) looks like this:

```
ID   Category Animal Version Value 
100     A       Dog     1      20
100     B       Cat     2      50
100     C       Dog     3      50
200     A       Dog     1      100
200     A       Cat     2      100
300     B       Cat     1      80 
400     C       Dog     1      80
```

I need to have the row with the highest/max version for each group of ids listed.

So in other words, I'd want these showing:

```
ID   Category Animal Version Value 
100     C       Dog     3      50
200     A       Cat     2      100
300     B       Cat     1      80 
400     C       Dog     1      80
```

Is this possible?

Comment: a group would be all rows with the same id .. . . so in this case we have 4 groups - 100, 200, 300, 400.

Comment: Highest of what? Value, version,...

Comment: A pivot table is probably going to get you what you want.

Comment: Sorry, we'd want the row showing that contains the highest  version number for that group of IDs.

Comment: You want a formula to return the whole output table?

Comment: Ideally, yes, we need to show each of those max rows in one table.

Comment: Power Query / Get & Transform should be a good option.

Comment: you could copy paste the table then sort by version descending and then use remove duplicates based on the ID column.

Answer (score 0):

For a list without duplicates you can put [this](http://www.excelformeln.de/formeln.html?welcher=194) in cell `G2` **ARRAY-FORMULA: CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF(G$1:G2,A$1:A$99)=0)*(A$1:A$99<>""),0)),"")
```

This gives you a list with unique ID's. Now you can use the max formula to get the max version number of each ID. **ARRAY-FORMULA: CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$2000=G3,$D$2:$D$2000,0))
```

The rest can be done with `INDEX/MATCH` formulas.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Advanced Filter` with a formula criteria:

```
=D9=AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(A9=Table1[ID])*Table1[Version],1)
```

where D9 is the location of the first entry in the `Value` Column

#### Before applying Filter

[image]

#### After applying Filter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Example]

Suppose your data is in range `A1:E8`,

In cell `A11`, put in the following formula to find unique `ID`, drag it down until there is a `#N/A` error:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($A$10:A10,$A$2:$A$8),0),0))
```

In cell `B11`, put in the following formula and drag it down to find the latest `Version`:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$D$2:$D$8/($A$2:$A$8=A11),1)
```

In cell `C11`, `D11` and `E11`, put in the following formulas respectively and drag them down to find the corresponding `Category`, `Animal` and `Value`:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$8,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$8=A11)/($D$2:$D$8=B11),0),0))

=INDEX($C$2:$C$8,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$8=A11)/($D$2:$D$8=B11),0),0))

=INDEX($E$2:$E$8,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$2:$A$8=A11)/($D$2:$D$8=B11),0),0))
```

Let me know if there is any question. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Finding and showing the maxima/minima for grouped data with a **single formula** in **only one cell** can be done with the following formula:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(MyArray,MMULT(((ValueRange>TRANSPOSE(ValueRange))+(ValueRange=TRANSPOSE(ValueRange))-(GroupRange=TRANSPOSE(GroupRange)))*(GroupRange=TRANSPOSE(GroupRange)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(GroupRange),1,1,0))=0),FALSE,FALSE)
```

For an example, see this screenshot: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNcLj.png)

The output automatically adjusts for any number of groups in the data array.

With the operator `>` used in the formula, it will return the maximum. By using `<` it will return the minimum.

Note that the UNIQUE() function will only show distinct rows for each group maximum (see group 'Alpha' in screenshot).

If there is more than one maximum in a group and more than just the group and value column, the UNIQUE() function will show all distinct rows taking into account all columns (as can be seen for group 'Alpha' and 'Gamma' here: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Bym.png)).